# C2593 'operator +' is ambiguous

Tags: c++, class, memory, dynamic, operator-overloading

I just started using Dynamic memory so if this is an easy fix or my code is disgustingly messy I apologize.

main cpp:

```
void main() 
{
    theString s1("Crystal Bepsi ",14);
    theString s2;
    theString s3;

    cout << s1[8] << endl;
    s1[8] = 'P';

    s2 = "tastes great!";

    // This performs concatenation

    s3 = s1 + s2;
}
```

theString.h:

```
theString operator + (theString right)
    {lengthCounter = lengthCounter + right.Length();
        int counter = right.Length();
        for (int i = 0; i < right.Length(); i++)
        {
            right.returnString(counter + i) = stringArray[i];
        }
         return right;
      }
```

I'm getting the operator + is ambiguous error and im not too sure where I have gone wrong, This is a school assignment so I am not allowed to use strings as variables just character arrays.  I left out a huge chunk of code, I only left in the operator that is malfunctioning, the overload is inside the class. 
Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: We need the full code. Looks like that you have a similar operator

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @Jazzbear  First of all the showed operator does not make sense. Secondly you should show all operators operator + declared for the class.

Comment: What does the error message actually say, word-for-word? Are there any other output meessages that tell you WHY the operator is ambiguous? Also, your `operator+` does not appear to actually be performing any concatenation at all. It is just manipulating the right-hand string and then returning it as-is. What is `returnString()` doing? Where is the output allocated to be the combined length of the two strings? Even if you declared `operator+` to prevent ambiquity, this code still looks all wrong.

Comment: @Jazzbear  I can guess that on the one hand you declared the operator as a member function and on the other hand you also declared a friend operator operator +.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow
Sorry the code wasn't specific enough I felt the program was too long to add into the post, but next time I for sure will include the rest. 
The problem ended up being the variables used in the overload were declared dynamically and I wasn't protecting from memory leaks. Sorry if the question was frustrating, I'll do better in my next problem.